# How do I access a custom TableViewCell by index?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

In Swift 3, is there a way to access a `UITableViewCell` by index (e.g. 0)?

The big picture idea of what I am trying to do is that I have a `TableViewController` and have a custom `UITableViewCell` (call it `MyCell`) with an imageView that I want to clear out (i.e. `imageView.image = nil`).

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to set the `imageView` to `nil` within the `TableViewController` since I can't access the cell itself.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please describe where you want to set `imageView's` image to nil.

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: you can use `tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath)`?

Comment: Do not manipulate the cell directly. Use a corresponding property in the data source array, change that and reload the row or the entire table view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
```

source: 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow

example:

```
let index = IndexPath(row: 3, section: 2)
let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at index)
```

For accessing to image you can do as bellow:

```
self.table.cellForRow(at index).image
```

Comment: Thank you this answer helped me the most.

Answer (score 2):

Like this (I'm assuming you mean by indexPath; if you want to get an array index of visible cells, please modify your question or reply):

```
let myCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: myIndexPath) as! myCustomCellType
```

...all of the 'my...' object types are whatever you want them to be; 'myIndexPath' is the indexPath of your cell.

> Edit

**How to access `UIImageView` ?**

By the above code you get the cell object now use below code to access the `imageView`

```
cell.imageView.image  = "img_name.png"
```

Comment: Yeah Right! (y)

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy: Haha. Gotta triple-check the details. Not saying I generally do, but do as I say, not as I do? :)

Comment: Didn't catched you :/

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy: Just joking. Though I was immediately upset with myself, for not noticing that you also have the var name wrong: I used 'myCell', not 'cell'.

Comment: Hahaha I recently noticed, but thats ok here because there is only single line for OP I added and it is understandable. If there is bunch of code then OP will also confused, :p Enjoy buddy. (y)